# What is an Anderson-Braun neutron counter?

Tags: experimental-physics, neutrons, particle-detectors

I found this type of tool reading an article ("A neutron monitor with silver activation") but surfing the internet I can not find an explanation of what it is and how it works.

It's probably a basic question for who's in the field but I'm new in the field of revelation techniques and I'm not sure where to look for this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google is your friend.](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Andersson-Braun%20neutron%20counter) Andersson and Braun designed a neutron rem meter with a cylindrical BF3 or 3HE tube surrounded by a PE moderator. [These slides](https://www.nrc.gov/docs/ML1122/ML11229A713.pdf) give you a nice overview and explain the main feature of AB detectors:

> To reduce the instrument’s over-response to low energy neutrons, they incorporated a borated plastic sleeve (7.6 cm diameter) around the detector tube and inner moderator.

[image: From https://www.nrc.gov/docs/ML1122/ML11229A713.pdf]

You can also find a good introduction in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016890029091373J), explaining what an "rem counter" is and how Andersson-Braun detectors work:

> It is well known that the solution usually adopted by health physicists for the determination of the old concept of maximum dose equivalent (MADE) is that of using a so-called **rem counter**. This is an instrument in which a detector with a high efficiency to thermal neutrons is placed inside a moderator- attenuator of such a nature and geometry that the response function of the rem counter reproduces the curve of the conversion coefficient from neutron fluence to dose equivalent on an energy range as wide as possible. The best instrument of this type is the **Andersson-Braun** (A-B) rem counter [...], whose response is considered acceptable, for radiation protection purposes, from thermal to 14 MeV neutrons.

Comment: thank you very much for the advice and for the complete answer! I tried to search on google but I did not find anything that would explain this type of detectors from the base.

Comment: So what do you expect from a final answer? A-B is quite basic already. If you are after pure neutron detector basics, that would be another question.

Comment: Yes, I probably need a base on neutron detectors in general.

Comment: So I'd consider this answer as complete with regards to the question in the title. You can accept this answer (green check), try to study the provided  literature, and then ask a new, more specific question about neutron detectors in general.